# android app urlconnection get request wont work

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, get

I am having a problem.

I can't figure out why the following code won't work.

It's a simple app that sends a GET request to some php fragment that supposed to insert a row in a table.

I can't understand why it doesn't work.

Please help.

java:

```
package com.example.michael.biyum;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    Button startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    final TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://www.chatty.co.il/biyum.php?q=mkyong");
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = isw.read();
                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    data = isw.read();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GET:"+current,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    System.out.print(current);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }


    });
   }
 }
```

php:

```
   <?php
require('connect.inc.php');
$update_offline="INSERT INTO offline_waiters (user_partner,mail,chat_room) VALUES(0,'gavno','gavno')";
$query_run= mysqli_query($conn,$update_offline);

echo "new";



?>
```

It's a simple test that should enter a new row in my table.

When I make the request manualy via a browser it works fine.

Once again please help me understand where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the network operation off of the main thread.

I just got this working and tested using an AsyncTask:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://www.chatty.co.il/biyum.php?q=mkyong");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = isw.read();
            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                data = isw.read();
                result.append(current);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GET:"+result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Just execute the AsyncTask from your click listener:

```
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    });
```

Result in the Toast:

[image]